# Is there a way in python to have two inputs in one line where the second input is not necessary (won't crash if it doesn't exist)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input

I've been playing with python, trying to think of some string problems for my nephew, and the program I "thought of" was to "implement" in a loose sense the cd, cd.. and pwd commands using strings.

```
pwd = "\home"
cdDot =  []
run = 1
cd = 0
while(run):
    x = input()
    if(x == "pwd"):
        print(pwd)          
    elif(x == "cd"):
        y = input()
        cdDot.append(y)
        pwd = pwd + "\\" + y
        cd+=1            
    elif(x == "cd.." and len(cdDot)>0):
        pwd = pwd[:-len(cdDot[cd-1])-1]
        cdDot.pop(-1)
        cd-=1  
    elif(x == "exit" or x=="exit\n"):
        run = 0
print("IT PHONE HOME")
```

Example of it working:
**pwd**
\home
**cd

folder1**
**pwd**
\home\folder1
**cd**
folder2
**pwd**
\home\folder1\folder2
**cd**
**folder3**
**pwd**
\home\folder1\folder2\folder3
**cd..**
**pwd**
\home\folder1\folder2
**cd**
**folder4**
**pwd**
\home\folder1\folder2\folder4
**cd..**
**cd..**
**pwd**
\home\folder1
**cd..**
**pwd**
\home
**cd**
**folder5**
**pwd**
\home\folder5

Bolded are the inputs. Basically **pwd** just prints in which "folder" we are, **cd** strcat's the input onto the **pwd** and **cd..** removes the last current strcat. I've been wondering if there is a way to program it so that you input in one line:
**cd folder1**
Right now, I have to input **cd** first and then the folder I want to go in.
**Is it possible to input and check at the same time what the first of the inputs is?**

So from needing an enter between "cd" and "string". From:

cd {enter}
folder1 {enter}
.... other commands

To:

cd folder1 {enter}

Comment: You can check if the string starts with `"cd "`, and then you can slice that off and see what the rest of the string is.

Comment: Additionally: `if` is not a function, so you don't need those extra parentheses. `if(x == "pwd"):` should be just `if x == "pwd":`.

Comment: The `pwd`, `run`, `cd` variables are redundant. Use a `while True:` loop and then `break` to exit. The stack can be initialised to `['/home']` and folder names appended/popped as needed. To get the pwd, do `print('/'.join(stack))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string by spaces:

```
one_line_input = input()
my_inputs = my_one_line_input.split(" ")
```

The second line split your string by spaces.
With this code if you have something like this for input:

```
cd /folder1
```

then in `my_inputs` variable you have an array with 2 string items like this:

```
['cd', '/folder1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to take multiple inputs at a time?

You could store the multiple inputs in an array

```
x = [str(x) for x in input(">").split()]

# eg input: > pwd 
# here, x = ['pwd']
# 
# eg input: > cd folder1
# here, x = ['cd', 'folder1']
```

Then, while checking the if conditions; test `x[0] == foo` instead of `x`.

Comment: Yeah, but at the same time check. So if the input is:
cd folder1
then it will see that the command used is cd which means that string that comes after the space is concatenated on the pwd variable, which just holds the current "directory". However, if the command is not "cd", but "cd.." or "pwd", then the 2nd argument of the input is non-existant.
And keep doing that until "exit" is inputted.

Comment: Yes even if the input is not 'cd' but 'cd.'. or 'pwd', it will be stored in x[0]. It is basically the same solution as @noor ali.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
>>> cmd, *args = input('> ').split(' ')
> pwd
>>> print(cmd, args)
pwd []
>>> cmd, *args = input('> ').split(' ')
> cd folder1
>>> print(cmd, args)
cd ['folder1']
>>> cmd, *args = input('> ').split(' ')
> echo hi StackOverflow is great!
>>> print(cmd, args)
echo ['hi', 'StackOverflow', 'is', 'great!']
>>>
```

This way, the args are optional, and if provided you can use them as you need, based on the cmd used.

Or even, keep all the args together like this:

```
>>> cmd, *args = input('> ').split(' ', 1)
> pwd
>>> print(cmd, args)
pwd []
>>> cmd, *args = input('> ').split(' ', 1)
> echo hi StackOverflow is great!
>>> print(cmd, args)
echo ['hi StackOverflow is great!']
```